# How to see the GPS in a Windows notebook

Tags: windows, gps

How to determine if a Windows machine has a GPS and how to see it in the device manager?

How to query the GPS to get the location info?

Comment: Do you mean actual, literal GPS positioning, or just the ability to know where you are? These days anything with wifi can always know where you are. GPS doesn't work indoors, wifi works unless you're out in the middle of nowhere. You don't even need to actually connect to any wifi, the machine only needs to be able to see it. An internet connection is needed, though, to translate that information - that's also why phones are better at it, they can use phone masts too.

Comment: Most geolocation is performed through WiFi.  The likelihood of your laptop having an actual GPS hardware is very small. To even get partial functionality you would need software from the manufacture.

Comment: The usual way to use a GPS device is to open its virtual (or real) COM port and then use the NMEA stream it sends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and fastest way is to install Maps application from Microsoft Store. Start it, enable location and if you get your location you have GPS.

To access the coordinates via program you can use this powershell script (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46287884/2908599) answer):

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Device #Required to access System.Device.Location namespace
$GeoWatcher = New-Object System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher #Create the required object
$GeoWatcher.Start() #Begin resolving current locaton

while (($GeoWatcher.Status -ne 'Ready') -and ($GeoWatcher.Permission -ne 'Denied')) {
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 #Wait for discovery.
}  

if ($GeoWatcher.Permission -eq 'Denied'){
    Write-Error 'Access Denied for Location Information'
} else {
    $GeoWatcher.Position.Location | Select Latitude,Longitude #Select the relevent results.
}
```

The expected result is something like:

```
Latitude Longitude
-------- ---------
 50,1121    8,6834
```

Comment: This isn’t the way to check whether GPS is present/used. It will use _any_ geolocation source, which is typically Wi-Fi.